# Error installing rpy2 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, r, linux, ubuntu, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 in Linux and I keep getting these errors. I updated my Python to 3.6 as well. I have Ubuntu 16.4

```
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-2.9.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    rpy2 is no longer supporting Python < 3. Consider using an older rpy2 
release when using an older Python release.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yEavWp/rpy2/
```

Comment: Newer Debian/Ubuntu releases have `python3-rpy2` as well.  The error message clearly tells you  that `python2` still gets into the mix.

Comment: So how would I fix this? I cannot remove python2 also.

Comment: You made a choice by sticking with Ubuntu 16.04. That platform has `python-rpy2` ready for you to use--as I maintained that package for almost a decade.  But if you want python3 there, you must be comfortable rebuilding your components.  It is a trade-off---your call.  I run Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: How do I access this already available rpy2 from a python console? As it gives me this error: " ImportError: No module named rpy2 "

Comment: Please learn about "how do I install a package on Ubuntu".  I can't teach you all that here in a 500 char box, sorry.

Comment: I will check that! Thank you!